# how to use a keyboard macro in a lisp function until it fails

Tags: emacs, lisp

right now I have a keyboard macro defined and named, and i want to make a lisp function which goes to the top of the buffer, and does:

```
i = 1
do{
    run macro
    if macro hit the end of the buffer, break out of the loop
    insert i
    i++
}while(true)
```

here's what's in my .emacs

```
(fset 'next-id
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([19 73 68 61 34 13 67108896 19 34 13 2 23] 0 "%d")) arg)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x n") 'next-id)
```

how would I go about this?

Comment: What happens when you hit the end of the buffer?  It just keeps adding numbers?

Comment: I want it to stop adding numbers when the macro hits the end of the buffer, so that pseudocode is actually not completely right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(defun apply-macro-to-buffer (&optional macro)
  "Apply last keyboard macro to the buffer"
  (interactive "CEnter the name of the macro to apply: ")
  (or macro
      (progn
        (if (null last-kbd-macro)
            (error "No keyboard macro has been defined"))
        (setq macro last-kbd-macro)))
  (let ((end-marker (copy-marker (point-max)))
        (i 1))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (and  (< (point) end-marker))
        (let ((mark-active nil))
          (execute-kbd-macro macro))
        (insert (format "%d\n" i))
        (setq i (1+ i))))))
```

To do the same for a regular command, try this:

```
(defun apply-command-to-buffer (command)
  "Apply a command to the buffer"
  (interactive "CEnter the name of the command to apply: ")
  (let ((end-marker (copy-marker (point-max)))
        (i 1))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (and  (< (point) end-marker))
        (call-interactively command)
        (insert (format "%d\n" i))
        (setq i (1+ i))))))
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work right. The macro is supposed to delete some text, but when used here it seems to just insert the text before what it usually deletes.

Comment: also it starts at 2 instead of 1

Comment: @Bwmat I don't think your macro does what you think it does.  The code clearly inserts `i` before incrementing it.  Perhaps your macro is stepping on the inserted text.  Note: the `insert` function moves the point to the end of the inserted text.

Comment: oh, I know what happened, the last-kbd-macro is not the one i wanted to use. I have a named macro, 'next-id' that I want to use, how do I invoke this function with that?(while editing a buffer)

Comment: @Bwmat I added a prompt for the macro name.  Note: it prompts for any command name, I don't think there's a way to limit it to just keyboard macros.

Comment: doesn't work, complains about macros needing to be strings or vectors. I've updated my question to show how the macro is defined in my .emacs

Comment: That's because it's no longer a plain macro, it's a function/command whose body executes a macro.  A keyboard macro looks more like:  `(fset 'yyyyo "\C-n\C-n\C-etrey\C-x")`

Comment: So... if you want to execute a *command*, let me update the answer to have an option to do that.

Comment: `execute-kbd-macro` expects its argument to be a string or vector. Replacing `(execute-kbd-macro macro)` with `(execute-kbd-macro (format "%s" macro))` coerces `macro` into a string.

Answer (score 3):

Srsly. Here's how to do it: `C-u 0 F4`

Comment: Some background on "Infinite arguments" in Emacs: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfiniteArgument